# How to access the BIC value in Stata after being calculated by estat ic?

Tags: variables, stata

[This document](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/restatic.pdf) explains that the values of AIC and BIC are stored in `r(S)`, but when I try `display r(S)`, it returns "type mismatch" and when I try `sum r(S)`, it returns "r ambiguous abbreviation".

Sorry for my misunderstanding this `r(S)`, but I'll appreciate it if you let me know how I can access the calculated BIC value.

Answer (score 0):

The document you refer to mentions that `r(S)` is a matrix. The `display` command does not work with matrices. Try `matrix list`. Also see `help matrix`.

For example:

```
clear
sysuse auto
regress mpg weight foreign
estat ic
matrix list r(S)
matrix S=r(S)
scalar aic=S[1,5]
di aic
```

Answer (score 0):

The same document that you cited explains that `r(S)` is a matrix. That explains the failure of your commands, as `summarize` is for summarizing variables and `display` is for displaying strings and scalar expressions, as their help explains. Matrices are neither.

Note that the document you cited

http://www.stata.com/manuals13/restatic.pdf

is at the time of writing not the most recent version

http://www.stata.com/manuals14/restatic.pdf

although the advice is the same either way.

Copy `r(S)` to a matrix that will not disappear when you run the next r-class command, and then list it directly. For basic help on matrices, start with

```
help matrix
```

Here is a reproducible example. I use the Stata 13 version of the dataset because your question hints that you may be using that version:

```
. use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/sysdsn1
(Health insurance data)

. mlogit insure age male nonwhite

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -555.85446  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -545.60089  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -545.58328  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -545.58328  

Multinomial logistic regression                 Number of obs     =        615
                                                LR chi2(6)        =      20.54
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0022
Log likelihood = -545.58328                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0185

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      insure |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Indemnity    |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Prepaid      |
         age |  -.0111915   .0060915    -1.84   0.066    -.0231305    .0007475
        male |   .5739825   .2005221     2.86   0.004     .1809665    .9669985
    nonwhite |   .7312659    .218978     3.34   0.001      .302077    1.160455
       _cons |   .1567003   .2828509     0.55   0.580    -.3976773    .7110778
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Uninsure     |
         age |  -.0058414   .0114114    -0.51   0.609    -.0282073    .0165245
        male |   .5102237   .3639793     1.40   0.161    -.2031626     1.22361
    nonwhite |   .4333141   .4106255     1.06   0.291     -.371497    1.238125
       _cons |  -1.811165   .5348606    -3.39   0.001    -2.859473   -.7628578
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estat ic

Akaike's information criterion and Bayesian information criterion

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Model |        Obs  ll(null)  ll(model)      df         AIC        BIC
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
           . |        615 -555.8545  -545.5833       8    1107.167    1142.54
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
               Note: N=Obs used in calculating BIC; see [R] BIC note.

. ret li

matrices:
                  r(S) :  1 x 6

. mat S = r(S)

. mat li S

S[1,6]
            N         ll0          ll          df         AIC         BIC
.         615  -555.85446  -545.58328           8   1107.1666   1142.5395
```

The BIC value is now in `S[1,6]`.